# How I can work with Excel 2007 and Excel 2003 (Excel Chart) from win32 application using COM?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl, charts

How I can work with Excel 2007 and Excel 2003 (Excel Chart) from win32 application using COM?
Where I can see any examples (for Visual Studio 2003) or manual of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `#import`, you can get VC++ to generate lots of smart pointer code for interacting with COM. This is my preferred method for Office automation from C++. Add this to the top of your source file to generate the files and include the appropriate generated files:

```
#import "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE11\\MSO.DLL"
#import "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\EXCEL.EXE"
```

Obviously you may need to change the file paths. You can also use a typelib ID, which is probably a better solution if you are in a multiple-developer environment. There are other issues such as name collisions, and you should take a look at the article at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/WTLExcel.aspx which summarizes it all quite well.

Now you can use Excel via `_com_ptr<T>`, `_bstr_t`, `_variant_t`, and other helper classes from VC++.

Comment: Have you got any source examples of working with Excel Chart, for instance, manipulate data, changing type of chart and any functions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any examples for you. If this was my project though I might consider playing around in VBA or C# to first get the hang of the chart API. The API is exactly the same as you would use through COM, except VBA and C# will be must faster and forgiving to work with for your experimenting. See also MSDN for the [Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.chart.aspx) documentation.

Comment: i found example, but it isn't working right.. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000657/working-with-excel-2007-from-win32-application-some-problems if you have a free time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[How To Create an Automation Client Project Using ATL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196135)